# get the line and page at the calling in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 02 pages

1.php

```
  function def($var){
      echo "$var";
    debug();
      }
```

2.php (calling page)

```
 def("test");
  debug();
```

create a debug small function

```
    function debug(){
     echo "called in script".$script;
     echo "<br>"
     echo "called at line".$at_line;
      }
```

How can I implement the function `debug()`  to get the information as described?

EDIT:
 I know we can use

`$file =  $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`//to get the script name

What is difference

```
  $arr = debug_backtrace();

  $file = $arr[0]['file'];//to get the script name
```

Which ways should use for my case.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily do it inline using the [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.
If you want to use a debug function call, you have to backtrack to the previous call using [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

Answer (score 1):

You want `debug_backtrace`. To see what kinds of information you can get out of it, try running this:

```
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```

in your debug function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the magic constants:

[PHP Magic Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: This (probably) won't work. Not that the magic constants don't do exactly what they say, but for this case, the person asking the question wants information about the function calling debug, an understandable request. Putting __ FILE __ in debug() will always yield the same answer, as one would expect, and it would be the file debug() is in. Similar results will occur for other magic constants.